# How to redirect requests to my URL to somefile.php not index.php

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

How can i redirect all the requests that are made to www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/index_main.php and then rewrite www.mysite.com/index_main.php as www.mysite.com

Comment: Doing that would cause users to be redirected in an endless loop, so I suspect that's not what you really want. Can you clarify your question to describe what it is you mean to accomplish?

Comment: I have no index.php in my root directory and don't want one and i want to treat another file as index.php. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Apache [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) directive to specify which file or files should be treated as the directory index.

Example:

```
DirectoryIndex index_main.php
```